# in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, c++-cli

When I'm trying serialize a class containing this property:

```
[NonSerialized]
property System::Collections::ObjectModel::ReadOnlyCollection<String^>^ IgnoredWords
```

I get a compilation error saying:

> fatal error C1093: API call
>   'DefineCustomAttribute' failed
>   '0x801311c0'

How do I tell the serializer that I do not want to serialize this property (and, yes, by default it tries to, which causes a run time error)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(inferring from xml-serialization tag) You want `[XmlIgnore]` for `XmlSerializer`.

`[NonSerialized]` is for `BinaryFormatter` etc, and only applies to fields, not properties (which is probably why you are getting `DefineCustomAttribute` failures).